# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout Collapsed Title Not Centered When Action Menu Icon Exists

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
    app:contentScrim="@color/purple_500"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:title="Sam Chen">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/sam" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Have tried following on `MaterialToolbar` but doesn't work:

```
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetEndWithActions="0dp"
```

Comment: why don't you add icon through action menu?

Comment: @Phúc Nguyễn I did.